# Why does Google's Android C2DM service require android version later than 2.2?

Tags: android, notifications, push, message, android-c2dm

Google's Cloud Messaging, previously called C2DM bata, recently rebranded to GCM, requires android 2.2 up. https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/
The question is why? What new features in 2.2 above do C2DM use that earlier versions do not support?

Comment: But still c2dm is deprecated. keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

C2DM has been introduced in 2.2, and ROms with previous firmware don't have specific services to handle intents of C2DM

Comment: thx, it seems c2dm service comes with Android Market (Google Play) app. This app also exist on pre-2.2 devices. Google explains that C2DM requires some framework API from post-2.2. But what exact methods/ classes introduced in 2.2 are used?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone here can answer that as it is a Google decision.

Keep in mind that most Android devices are already Android 2.3 and above.

http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html